# How to control volume with media keys?

Tags: audio, gentoo

My install: Gentoo + Xorg + i3 + PulseAudio.
`acpi_listen` gives correct output, like, VOLUP, VOLDOWN

But I can't figure out how to make these keys actually change the volume.

My laptop model is *HP Pavilion 15-n059sr*

Why the solution depends on the keyboard?

Comment: Kinda depends on the keyboard manufacturer and how they implemented them. What's the keyboard or laptop model number from the serial number plate underneath? Please find it then click on [edit] and hive us that very useful information by adding it to your original post.

Comment: also depends on the DE/WM in use, and how what gets mapped ...

Comment: @tink i3 is only a WM, right? I think normally it's a DE mapping?

Comment: Dunno what I3 is; but Fluxbox is a WM, and I have it mapped :D on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought such functionality comes with X11 itself, but as it turns out it comes with `xbindkeys`, which is a X11-related program that is in category *miscellaneous*.

To get multimedia keys(volume, brightness) working, create *~/.xbindkeysrc*. To get useful information(default file contents) on how the file is composed, call `xbindkeys -d`

```
# ~/.xbindkeysrc

#-----VOLUME-----#
#
# Decrease volume
"pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -1000"
   XF86AudioLowerVolume

# Increase volume
"pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +1000"
   XF86AudioRaiseVolume

# Mute volume
"pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle"
   XF86AudioMute


#----BACKLIGHT----#
#
# Increase backlight
"xbacklight -inc 10"
   XF86MonBrightnessUp

# Decrease backlight
"xbacklight -dec 10"
   XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

And add `xbindkeys` to autostart. I added it to *~/.xinitrc*

Keys like *Play, Next* are handled by your multimedia player.